# How to "read" a SWIFT message?

Tags: c#, banking, swift-mt

"SWIFT" meaning [Society for Worldwide Interbank Financial Telecommunication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9362)

I need to read some files and insert the data in a SQL Server database table using C#.NET.
The files are downloaded from a banking software (ABN Amro), and they contain (debit & credit) movements on the account.

It contains a lot of `:61:` and `:86:` "tags", it seems almost human readable, but it's not, especially when they're talking amounts, it's impossible to filter those out if you don't have the correct specs.

I'm searching like crazy but I can't find enough information, I mean a document that explains how to interprete these messages/files?  Not even on swiftcommunity.net... or maybe I'm not looking on the right spot.

Does that exists, and where?

Comment: *shudder*...SWIFT, FIX, FIXML...these are the paths to untold pain and suffering...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Swift mt940 file format has a header line, a footer line, some mandatory lines with information and then a bunch of lines meaning transactions. The lines start with a `:XX:` code to indicate what type of line it is.

If you google you can find the spec quite easy from a number of banks. for example:

- http://martin.hinner.info/bankconvert/swift_mt940_942.pdf
- http://www.bankmillennium.pl/static-content/EN/File_format_description_of_MT940_v20071205_1664350_588699.pdf

Comment: +1 That should get him going. IT is a "RTFM" case, but sometimes the manual is just not that easy to find.

Comment: @TomTom: indeed, I know it's a RTFM, but if you don't know what manual is the right one to read, it's really hard to RTFM ;)

Comment: @Filip De Vos: thanks man ! If I knew that it's an MT940 file format I would have found it already... so thank you for clearing out that one !

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of bank transmission formats.

Comment: Ideally you should subscribe to the Swift newsletters. They like to change the format every now and then. http://www.swift.com/support/drc/index.page?

Comment: The bank has to follow that change too then ;).  But I'll do, thanks :)

Comment: @MichaelBruyninckx This is why I did not complaint and upvoted the answer. Especially if you do not even know how the damn format is NAMED - SWIFT is not a good search term in google. Way too much noice. Even "SWIFT file format" likely leads to a lot of external stuff.

Comment: I knew that it was SWIFT, but "SWIFT" seems to be soooo much more than just one template to form message... I tried even "swift" and ":61:" or "swift" and ":86:" but never found anything that I searched for.  I knew that it was swift because the extension of the file was SWIFT :)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I am too late but I actually build an opensource library for this (http://raptorious.com/sharpmt940lib/). Maybe it can assist you?

Comment: Is this library still updated? I would like to download it. Thanks Jaco.

Comment: @JaimeGarcíaPérez it looks like it's here https://bitbucket.org/raptux/sharpmt940lib

Comment: Is this library still updated? I would like to download it.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I'm not actively working on it due to lack of time. The sources are available (again) at https://bitbucket.org/raptux/sharpmt940lib .